# outlook Addin Contact Details for Sender

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am developing code for capturing photo/picture for the recipient, while sending an email in the sending even of MS outlook.
Can you please suggest what is the best way to achieve it?

```
>     Outlook.NameSpace outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            Outlook.MAPIFolder contactsFolder =
                outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
                OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);

            Outlook.Items contactItems = contactsFolder.Items;

            try
            {
                Outlook.ContactItem contact =
                    (Outlook.ContactItem)contactItems.
                    Find(String.Format("[FirstName]='{0}' and "
                    + "[LastName]='{1}'", "firstName", "LastName"));
                if (contact != null)
                {
                    contact.Display(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The contact information was not found.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

In the try block, contact is null. Let us know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to understand your question better - you develop add-in in JS? or what? And you want to capture images- what kind- attachments /  images in body ? And what you want to do with this images.. tnx

Comment: Sorry I am developing on windows from application and I want to capture/get the  recipients photo .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, I very much doubt anybody would have a contact with the first name of "firstName" and last name of "LastName" - that is what your code is searching for.

Extract the sender email address and search for contacts with a matching Email1Address, Email2Address, or Email3Address.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I have supplied appropriate first name and last names. but the problem here is contactsFolder.Items count is showing up as 0. There is data in contactsFolder but item count is 0.